# how to use external (free available or paid) web services

Tags: web-services

how to use the external web service (paid or free) in the application. 
For example:
Here is the code snippet from one of the site (http://debugmode.net/2010/09/10/consuming-wcf-rest-service-in-asp-net-web-site/) which is using the self created service. But instead of it if one has to use the external service how should be proceeded?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{    

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {    
 }  

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{        
 WebClient proxy = new WebClient();     
 byte[] abc = proxy.DownloadData((new Uri("http://localhost:4567/Service1.svc/GetData"))); 
 Stream strm = new MemoryStream(abc);   
 DataContractSerializer obj = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));  
 string result = obj.ReadObject(strm).ToString();     
 TextBox1.Text = result; 
}
```

Comment: You should enclose your WebClient and Stream in a using statement because they implement IDisposable and you want their implementation Dispose() method to be called. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.  You are not referring to in which language you want to acces the webservice (I guess C#?). Please retag your question with the language. Thanks.